# Changing position of Bootstrap tooltip on Mobile Screen

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I want to change the data-placement of Bootstrap tooltip to **left** from right for **mobile screens only**. Right now its only showing **right** which is **ok** for **desktop screens only**. How can i achieve that?

```
            <a class="tooltip" href="javascript:;" data-toggle="tooltip" data-trigger="hover" data-placement="right" title="I am your tooltip">?</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use window.onresize event, it will detect the screensize and if the screensize is less than 768px, it will change the #myDiv tooltip position.

```
$(window).on('resize', function() {
    var pos = ($(window).width() < 768) ? 'left' : 'top';
    $("#myDiv").tooltip({'placement': pos});
}).trigger('resize');
```